# When $X\times (Y\times Z)=(X\times Y)\times Z$ in product topology?

Tags: general-topology

Under what conditions $X, Y, Z$ must have so $X\times (Y\times Z)=(X\times Y)\times Z$? and proof?

$X, Y, Z$ are topological spaces and $\times$ represents product topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: $$X\times(Y\times Z)\neq (X\times Y)\times Z$$ and: $$X\times(Y\times Z)\simeq (X\times Y)\times Z$$ where $\simeq$ stands for "being homeomorphic".

It can be shown that the function prescribed by $\langle x,\langle y,z\rangle\rangle\mapsto\langle\langle x,y\rangle,z\rangle$ is a homeomorphism.

Give it a try.

---

**Edit**:

Lemma: If in topology $\prod_{i\in I}X_{i}$ denotes a producttopology on
the spaces $X_{i}$ and is equipped with projections $\pi_{j}:\prod_{i\in I}X_{i}\rightarrow X_{j}$ for $j\in I$
then a function $f:R\rightarrow\prod_{i\in I}X_{i}$ is continuous if and
only if the compositions $\pi_{j}\circ f:R\rightarrow X_{j}$ are
continuous for each $j\in I$. Here $R$ denotes a topological space.

Have a look at the following functions between topological spaces.

$\phi:\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z\rightarrow X\times Y\times Z$
prescribed by $\langle\langle x,y\rangle,z\rangle\mapsto\langle x,y,z\rangle$

$\psi:X\times Y\times Z\rightarrow\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z$
prescribed by $\langle x,y,z\rangle\mapsto\langle\langle x,y\rangle,z\rangle$

$\pi_{XY}^{\left(XY\right)Z}:\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z\rightarrow X\times Y$
prescribed by $\langle\langle x,y\rangle,z\rangle\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$

$\pi_{Z}^{\left(XY\right)Z}:\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z\rightarrow X\times Y$
prescribed by $\langle\langle x,y\rangle,z\rangle\mapsto z$

$\pi_{X}^{XYZ}:X\times Y\times Z\rightarrow X$ prescribed by $\langle x,y,z\rangle\mapsto x$

$\pi_{Y}^{XYZ}:X\times Y\times Z\rightarrow Y$ prescribed by $\langle x,y,z\rangle\mapsto y$

$\pi_{Z}^{XYZ}:X\times Y\times Z\rightarrow Y$ prescribed by $\langle x,y,z\rangle\mapsto z$

$\pi_{X}^{XY}:X\times Y\rightarrow X$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x$

$\pi_{Y}^{XY}:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto y$

It is easy to verify that $\phi\circ\psi$ and $\psi\circ\phi$ are
indentity maps on the underlying sets (hence are bijections).

The compositions $\pi_{X}^{XYZ}\circ\phi:\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z\rightarrow X$,
$\pi_{Y}^{XYZ}\circ\phi:\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z\rightarrow Y$
and $\pi_{Z}^{XYZ}\circ\phi:\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z\rightarrow Z$
are continuous and from this we conclude that $\phi$ is continuous.

The compositions $\pi_{X}^{XY}\circ\pi_{XY}^{\left(XY\right)Z}\circ\psi:X\times Y\times Z\rightarrow X$
and $\pi_{Y}^{XY}\circ\pi_{XY}^{\left(XY\right)Z}\circ\psi:X\times Y\times Z\rightarrow Y$
are continuous and from this we conclude that $\pi_{XY}^{\left(XY\right)Z}\circ\psi$
is continuous.

The composition $\pi_{Z}^{\left(XY\right)Z}\circ\psi:X\times Y\times Z\rightarrow Z$
is continuous and combined with the continuity of $\pi_{XY}^{\left(XY\right)Z}\circ\psi$
this tells us that $\psi$ is continuous.

Proved is now that $\phi$ (and also $\psi$) is a homeomorphism so
that $\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z\simeq X\times Y\times Z$.

Likewise it can be shown that $X\times\left(Y\times Z\right)\simeq X\times Y\times Z$
and this allows the conclusion: $$\left(X\times Y\right)\times Z\simeq X\times\left(Y\times Z\right)$$

Comment: can I say since both of them are homomorphic to <x,y,z> so they are homomorphic to each other?

Comment: $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is an *element* of $X\times Y\times Z$ so not a topological space. The relation of "being homeomorphic" is a relation on topological spaces (not on elements of them). If it comes to topological spaces then "yes". If $A$ and $B$ are both homeomorphic with $C$ then $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: it is intuitively seems correct that whatever appears on one side is appearing on the other side exactly same element; so homeomorphism is a bijection (actually identity function). am I right? can you please tell what is a function can be as homeomorphism?

Comment: It is indeed evident that the function mentioned in my answer is a bijection. A function/morphism from a topological space to another topological space is a homeomorphism if and only if it is a bijection, is continuous and is open. So next to "it is a bijection" there are other things that must be proved.

Comment: I hope you managed allready. Just in case not: see my edit.

Comment: I couldn't do it myself and i felt shy to ask... thanks a lot :) I'll read it, just a bit takes time to understand it.

Comment: You are welcome. The most important part of it is actually the lemma. That must become a part of your luggage.

Answer (score 0):

Products are associative. One way to prove this is by applying the universal property of a product several times. An alternative way is to show that the map sending $(x,(y,z))$ to $((x,y),z)$ is a homeomorphism, using a basis of open sets for the product topology consisting of neighborhoods of the form $(U \times V) \times W$, for $U$,$V$ and $W$ open sets of the respective spaces.

Comment: Products are not *naturally* associative. You get ordered pairs of the form $(a,(b,c))$ and $((a,b),c)$. Of course you can unpack this in the natural way as $(a,b,c)$ but still.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Wait, so now I'm confused. Does this mean that a proof applying the universal property several times won't work?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one since I'm unfamiliar with the universal property in this case. But your other idea is right or mostly right I think.

Comment: It can be shown that both spaces $X\times(Y\times Z)$ and $(X\times Y)\times Z$ with appropriate projections serve as a product of $X,Y,Z$. From that you are allowed to conclude that the spaces are isomorphic (i.e. homeomorphic in topology). In topology products are associative *up to isomorphisms*.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Products *are* naturally associative, the isomorphisms $X \times (Y \times Z) \cong X \times Y \times Z \cong (X \times Y) \times Z$ are [natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) in $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. I think what you meant to say is perhaps that these weren't directly equal?

Comment: @Najib Oh yes of course. I even contradicted myself somewhat. It was quite late at that point.